# Error when using ggplot2 with rpy2

Tags: python, ggplot2, rpy2

I'm reproducing the test proposed by rpy2 tutorial. See the code below:

```
import math, datetime
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')

datasets = importr('datasets')
mtcars = datasets.mtcars

gp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars)

pp = gp + \
     ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg') + \
     ggplot2.geom_point()

pp.plot()
```

But, i find the error below:

> AttributeError: 'ListVector' object has no attribute 'plot'

Thank you for help

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are running? Because mtcars=datasets.mtcars is wrong. It should read mtcars = datasets.__rdata__.fetch('mtcars')['mtcars']. With this correction your code above works for me.